# Using connection string from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, connection-string

I try to connect to my database and I can do that using following code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn =
    new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=DocumentManager; Persist Security Info=True; Integrated Security=True")) 
{ ... }
```

But, when I try this:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnection"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) { ... }
```

it doesn't work anymore. My Connection String looks like this:

```
<add name="DatabaseConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=DocumentManager; Persist Security Info=True; Integrated Security=True" />
```

And, I can read the `connectionString` variable and it looks exactly like the string in the first case.

Comment: What you mean by `it doesn't work anymore.`?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: There is no error. I try to display data from database and there is no data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your in-code connection string has an escaped "\" in it.

Try changing your web.config to:

```
<add name="DatabaseConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=DocumentManager; Persist Security Info=True; Integrated Security=True" />
```

The "\" does not need to be escaped in your web.config.

This is an example of [escaping the backslash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DatabaseConnection");
```